# Running selenium webdriver in AWS EC2 linux

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2

I installed selenium on Amazon Linux AMI. I try to use python to activate it.
The error show up. I do not know what is supposed to mean. Can chrome webdriver run on that environment.

My code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/ec2-user/dlfjj/bin/chromedriver")
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/dlfjj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/home/ec2-user/dlfjj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`
```

update:
There is new error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/dlfjj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/ec2-user/dlfjj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/ec2-user/dlfjj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/ec2-user/dlfjj/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error states ...

```
'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions
```

... which means that it cannot be executed. It should work if you add the execute bit in the EC2 instance

```
$ chmod +x /home/ec2-user/dlfjj/bin/chromedriver
```